# JQuery/JavaScript addClass doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which contains elements. When I click on one element an action will occur. During the action time I want to make my div colors change to black & white and after the action it will reset the color.

So I create a simple css3 class :

```
gray {
    background-color:red;
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

And in my script I have two functions :

```
function enableWaitState( ) {
   $($("#chart")).addClass( "gray"); 
}

function disableWaitState( ) {
    $($("#chart")).removeClass( "gray");
}
```

in my javascript code I write the method which is called when clicking on a button:

```
function back() {
    enableWaitState( ); 
    // here doing some javascript code
    disableWaitState(  );
}
```

}

Unfortunately it doesn't work. But If I make an ajax call between enableWaitState() and disableWaitState(), it works!

Any ideas?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu That won't make any difference.

Comment: The code you provided is not enough to reproduce your problem here. Please create a [mcve] inside the question, (using the `<>` button), linking required external resources and making sure you problem can be experienced.

Comment: Just a guess: is '// here doing some javascript code' a synchronous computation? In that case you won't see a change of classes since after the (single threaded) execution of the function has returned the state of the class didn't change. In that case you need to change the computation into an asynchronous execution.

Comment: @ATN54 check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780090/jquery-javascript-addclass-doesnt-work/45780606#45780606

Answer (score 1):

You need to remve additional `$()` from your selector.

```
function enableWaitState( ) {
   $("#chart").addClass( "gray"); 
}

function disableWaitState( ) {
    $("#chart").removeClass( "gray");
}
```

Also this code will work only after chart element is loaded in the DOM. You can use console to check that:

```
 console.log($("#chart").length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 function enableWaitState() {
   $("#chart").addClass("gray"); 
 }

function disableWaitState() {
    $("#chart").removeClass("gray");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement of enabling and disabling background-color of div, i think that you want a blink effect when user clicks on elements within div.

Just check the code snippet below.

```js
function blinkEffect() {
  let elem = '#chart';
  $(elem).addClass('gray');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(elem).removeClass('gray');
  }, 200);
}

$('#btn1, #btn2, p').on('click', function() {
  blinkEffect();
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 600;
}

.gray {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='chart'>
  Some elements in this div to change background color on click and reset it after 200ms<br><br>
  <button id='btn1'>Btn 1</button><br><br>
  <button id='btn2'>Btn 2</button>
  <p>Welcome..<br>I am a paragraph...!!! <br>Click me to see the change</p>
</div>
```

Hope, it works for you.

Comment: So, It's me again for more details. I'm using DevExtreme and the code is executed when a click an o bar in a chart. Now I'm sure that it works if a synchronized ajax call is done.

Comment: But doens't work if I run javascript only like : var clickedPoint = e.target;
   var length = responseData[depth].values.length;
   var index = -1;
   var name = "";
   for(i = 0; i< length; i++) {
    if ( responseData[depth].values[i].name == clickedPoint._dataItem.argument ) {
      name = responseData[depth].values[i].name;  
      index = i;
      break;
    }
   }

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution

My probleam was :

```
function back() {
    enableWaitState( ); 
    // here doing some javascript code
    disableWaitState(  );
}
```

The UI was never updated.

The solution is :

```
        enableWaitState( depth); 
        setTimeout( function() {        
          // here doing some javascript code...
        disableWaitState( depth );
       }, 50 );
```

Explanation : The function enableWaitState() add a class in the DOM and BECAUSE the javascript code now wait 50 milliseconds before running the UI has the time to refresh itself.

Comment: Pleae close the question then, so that it will dissapear from open queue.